# Can't work out why <p> and <h3> are styled like hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to front-end, this will be my first website.
I am using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and Flask.

The problem that I am having is that the following code is being style like a link when it is meant to be plain text. It is blue, when I hover the mouse over it it turns blue and becomes underlined.

```
<div class="container col-md-6 col-lg-5">
    <hr>
    <p class="lead" id="repo-title">Welcome to the repository of my publications.</p>
    <p id="repo-intro">Introduction to repository. This is the sum of my work, from many different projects. It is listed in chronological order. Use the navigation on the left-side to filter through the repository by subject, project or publication format.</p>
</div>
```

I don't believe that I have used any Bootstrap classes that could cause this.
When I use Developer Mode in Firefox I noticed that is inheriting the following style:

```
a:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
}
```

from `_reboot.scss:13` , which appears to be a Bootstrap file. Though I haven't noticed anything that could be causing the elements to be underlined or for the cursor to change to a little hand.

I have tried to rectify this with a CSS style such as:

```
#repo-title, #repo-intro
{
    color:black;
}

#repo-title:hover, #repo-intro:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

This changed the font color, but didn't remove the underline nor the cursor change when it hovers over the text.

Here is my custom CSS stylesheet, in case I am  unknowingly causing this issue:

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}  

#headline 
{
    font-size: 64px;
    color:white;
}
#headline:link, #headline:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#headline:hover, #headline:active
{
    color:white;
}

#top-banner
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/*NAVVY*/

.navvy
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navvy li
{
    display: inline;
}

.navvy li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(0,123,255);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.navvy-link a:hover
{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.822);
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navvy li a.active
{
    background-color:rgb(0,123,255);
    color:white;
}

.navvy .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navvy-link, .active {display: none;}
    .navvy a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
      font-size: 40px;
    }
    .navvy li a{width: 90%;}
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navvy.responsive {position: relative;}
    .navvy.responsive .icon 
    {
        padding-top: 11px;
        padding-right: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .navvy.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: grid;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 25px;
    }

    .navvy.responsive li
    {
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
    }
  }
hr
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
/*HOME*/
img#bust
{
    width:75%;
    height: auto;
}



/*REPOSITORY*/


#main-content
{
    display:flex;
    padding:2rem;
}

#repo-nav
{
    order:1;
}

#repo-cards
{
    flex:1;
    order:2;
}



/*EVENTS*/
.container.news
{
   display: grid;
   justify-content:center;
}
.news
{
   justify-self:center;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're styled like hyperlinks because they *are* hyperlinks. You've got an unclosed `<a>` element somewhere above the HTML that you've posted.

Comment: Yes you were right. I feel silly for posting this on StackOverflow. Though thanks for reminding of how literal these languages are. That seems like a valuable lesson to remember.

Answer (score 0):

1. use a ide such as submlime text or webstorm to check
   unclose tags and code errors, probably you don't use correct form of
   tags or missing  somewhere.
2. create new page with simple html form for check the problem occurs on all pages
3. use ctrl+u in browser for check errors (missing tags and errors shows with red text)
4. disable all browser extensions and use incognito  mode
5. for override bootstrap style codes you can use !important.

ex:

```
#repo-title:hover, #repo-intro:hover
{
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will look for that extension in VSCode.
i can see myself using CTRL + U frequently.
Have a nice day.